# php code/formula to encrypt a 2 digit value with the 2 decimals..,

Tags: php, encryption

So , i want to create an authorisation code system for cashiers,

Right now , l use the 2 first digit added together to form a sum... then the 3rd digit is a multiplicator...

so 342 = 3+4=7  and 7 * 2 = 14...
so for the number 14 i send auth 342... or 432, or 612 or 162 etc...

my problem is how to get a prime number.. example 25.....
another problem is how to create php code to do reverse... get the digits from the number...

from 14.. get to 342 or 432, etc.....

Any ideas ? main purpose is be able to think and say a authorisation code while on the road...

the system will apply result as a perc discount....

so i can create a 50% discount with 915 code... 9+1=10 * 5 = 50

Comment: So when a user figures it out and types 999...? You shouldn't be creating these things yourself without sufficient relevant knowledge of cryptography.

Comment: 25 is not a prime number... it's a square number, and in your example you could get to it with 415 or 145. As Waleed Khan says, it won't take long for one of the brighter cashiers to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is similar to [format-perserving encryption](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2011/11/10/format-preserving-encryption-or-how-to/), which is a nontrivial undertaking to implement securely.

When you're working with cryptography, you generally want something that is:

- Straightforward to reason about
- Simple to implement, without tons of caveats and opportunities for error
- Remarkably well-studied by academics and industry experts to the point of being *boring*

Format-preserving encryption, conversely, is:

- A quagmire of complex circumstances
- Rife with opportunities for implementation error
- Relatively unstudied by industry experts
- An area of intrigue (read: *not boring*) for academics

However, what you're describing sounds like an attempt to mix format-preserving encryption with **textbook RSA** (also known as "unpadded" or "unarmored" RSA). If you want your scheme to be secure, *don't do that*.

Have you considered HMAC-SHA256 instead?